# Null values reading data from Excel using ADO

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, ado

I am reading data from an Excel 2007 spreadsheet using ADO. Setting up the connection is easy:

```
Dim ado As ADODB.Connection
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFilename.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
ado.Open
```

I can call `ado.OpenSchema` without any trouble on this object. However, when I try to query the data:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
Set rs = ado.Execute("SELECT * FROM [Current Work Load$]")
```

I simply get a table full of Nulls.

This is mentioned as an issue on the [Microsoft Support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) - but I have explicitly enabled "Import Mode" (as you can see in the code above - `IMEX=1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Execute method does not return any records as it is for action queries.
Your might want to try the OpenRecordset method.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
Set rs = ado.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Current Work Load$]")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the ADO connection strings here are unbelievably picky.  I've gotten reading the spreadsheets to work but with a slightly different connection string:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + @";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;IMEX=1";

(I don't have the XML after the Excel 12.0 declaration).

Comment: or the HDR=NO; which depends on whether there is one.

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can read Excel workbooks and enables you to access any cells without the kinds of issues / limatations you can run into with ADO.

You can see live C# & VB samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

As well as using `IMEX=1` in the connection string, you need to review a couple of registry keys. For more details, see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10102515/15354).

Comment: Link broken.  Is there another source for the registry key solution?

Comment: @sigil: I've changed the link to another SO answer, which has the same content as the aforementioned blog post (minus the comments).